# How to pass iterator list in Struts 2 to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend class="legendtitle">DEDUCTIONS</legend>
  <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing= "0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Component</div></td>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Allocated</div></td>
    </tr>
       
    <s:iterator value="%{#resultLists.deductionLists}" id="hrEmpSalaryCompDeductionList" 
                                                   status="stat">
      <s:if test="%{#allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount > 0}">
        <tr>
          <td class="labelone1" >
            <div align="center">
              <s:property value="%{#allowanceList.componentDesc}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="dataone1" >
            <div align="right"> 
              <s:property value="%{#allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount}" />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </s:if>
    </s:iterator>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

I need to hide the whole fieldset if none of the value of `allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount` in iterator list `resultLists.deductionLists` is not greater than 0.

I thought of calling JavaScript and to pass the value of `resultLists.deductionLists` and then set a counter if any `allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount` being greater than 0.

But how can I pass the list value of `resultLists.deductionLists` to JavaScript and access all `allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount` out of it?

Comment: What is allowanceList ? Where is it ? Do you have a List of Lists, and another parallel List called allowanceList ? Or is it a List of Lists of Lists ? Your structure is not clear, I know how to fix your problem but to write a more specific answer I'd rather have the structure

Answer (score 0):

To hide whole `fieldset` you have to wrap it with `<s:if>` tag.

```
<s:if test="%{#allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount > 0}">
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend class="legendtitle">DEDUCTIONS</legend>
  <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing= "0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Component</div></td>
       <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Allocated</div></td>
       </tr>

    <s:iterator value="%{#resultLists.deductionLists}" id="hrEmpSalaryCompDeductionList" 
                                                   status="stat">
      
        <tr>
          <td class="labelone1" >
            <div align="center">
              <s:property value="%{#allowanceList.componentDesc}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="dataone1" >
            <div align="right"> 
              <s:property value="%{#allowanceList.allocatedSalAmount}" />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      
    </s:iterator>
  </table>
</fieldset>
</s:if>
```

because you can iterate only one list at a time in fieldset you can't have both lists iterated by the same iterator. You have to define the proper expression to evaluate in the `<s:if>` tag to decide whether you should display fieldset or not.